# How to create a 2D array using single array angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays

How can we create 2D array from single array

```
angular.forEach(angular.fromJson(value.resource_type_efforts), function (value1, key1) {
          $scope.data.resource_type.push(key1);
});
```

when I do **console.log($scope.data.resource_type)** output is :-

```
0 :  "Senior Software Engineer"
1 :  "Software Engineer"
2 :  "QA Engineer"
3 :  "UI Developer"
4 :  "UI Designer"
5 :  "UI Developer"
6 :  "QA Engineer"
7 :  "Software Engineer"
```

Now i need to split this array in 2-d array after every 4 values.

```
0:
  0 :  "Senior Software Engineer"
  1 :  "Software Engineer"
  2 :  "QA Engineer"
  3 :  "UI Developer"
1:
  0 :  "UI Designer"
  1 :  "UI Developer"
  2 :  "QA Engineer"
  3 :  "Software Engineer"
```

Please suggest some answers

Comment: Based on which condition you make 2 array from 1 array?

Comment: I just need to create 2d array for every 4 values from 1d array starting from 0th index.

Comment: I hope you got me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a little helper function using `Array.slice` like in this [little demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd0swhbx/1/). You could parse a number as `splitCount`. This number could be changed by yourself for your needs. It also collects the rest of your array e.g. you have 9 items in your initial array.

#### > <kbd>**[`fiddle demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fd0swhbx/1/)**</kbd>

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [
      "Senior Software Engineer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "QA Engineer",
      "UI Developer",
      "UI Designer",
      "UI Developer",
      "QA Engineer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "Software Engineer",
    ];

    $scope.normalizedArray = normalize($scope.myArray, 4);

    function normalize (myArray, splitCount) {
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < (myArray.length / splitCount); i++) {
        result[i] = myArray.slice(i*splitCount, (i*splitCount) + splitCount);
      }
      return result;
    }
});
```

---

In that way this should do it for you:

```
$scope.myData = normalize(angular.fromJson(value.resource_type_efforts), 4);
```

Comment: Thank you @lin your answer looks more dynamic using function. It helped, many thanks too you

Comment: @Ramkishan Glad to help ya.

Answer (score 0):

Take one output array and inside loop push value in temp variable when key got %4 == 0 push temp to output array and blank temp array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.resource_type_efforts = 
    [
        'Senior Software Engineer',
        'Software Engineer',
        'QA Engineer',
        'UI Developer',
        'UI Designer',
        'UI Developer',
        'QA Engineer',
        'Software Engineer'
    ];

    $scope.output = [];
    var temp = [];
    angular.forEach(angular.fromJson($scope.resource_type_efforts), function (value1, key1) 
    {

        temp.push(value1);
        if((key1+1)%4==0)
        {
            $scope.output.push(temp);
            temp = [];
        }
    });
    console.log($scope.output);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait I think @lin's answer look more dynamic

Comment: You have to check 4 in both case haha

Comment: In mine you can get it also